# Error al intentar hacer un PUT con axios

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, jpa, axios

Mi endpoint hacia donde quiero hacer el `PUT`:

```
    @RequestMapping(path = "/location", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public void updatePoi(Long idLocation, Location location) {
    location.setIdLocation(idLocation);
    myService.addLocation(location);
}
```

La clase `MyService` que implementa el método `addLocation`:

```
@Autowired
private LocationRepository locationRepo;
    @Override
@Transactional
public void addLocation(Location location) {
    locationRepo.save(location);
}
```

Y en mi frontend uso la siguiente función para conectar con mi endpoint y hacer el PUT:

```
    function editPoi (dataPoi) {
    
    try{
         const urlLoc =  `http://localhost:8080/location?idLocation` + dataLoc.idLocation
    
         axios.put(urlLoc,dataLoc);


    } catch(e){
         console.log(e);
      }
}
```

Me tira el error de:

> Unhandled Rejection (Error): Network Error

¿Alguien entiende donde está mi error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que veo aquí es la falta de algunas anotaciones fundamentales para que el servicio REST funcione según lo esperado.

Revisando la URL seria de esta forma: `http://localhost:8080/location?idLocation=1` más un cuerpo `dataLoc`.

En ese caso faltarían las anotaciones:

`@RequestParam(name = "idLocation")` con esta anotación le especificamos al servicio que `idLocation` lo recibiremos como parámetro.

`@RequestBody` con esta anotación marcamos cual objeto recibiremos como el cuerpo de la petición.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/location", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public void updatePoi(@RequestParam(name = "idLocation") Long idLocation, @RequestBody Location location) {
    location.setIdLocation(idLocation);
    myService.addLocation(location);
}
```